# recaptcha in a non-productive environment (is it worth it?)

Tags: selenium, recaptcha

I wonder what is the most appropriate way to automate the following captcha in a non-productive environment (if necessary). Take a look:

[image]

> a)Making use of a boot that allows you to obtain a user token from our
> session to be able to enter it through automation
>
> b)Using the click() method on the appropriate elements
>
> c)Using: document.getElementById("recaptchamsg").required = false;
>
> d) None, recaptcha must be disabled for the test to skip this step

Is it necessary at all? And in a production environment? What would it be the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if possible, `recaptcha` must definitively be disabled for the test to skip this step.
If it is not possible you will have to pass it with Selenium. How to do that depends on the type or `recaptcha` you have on your application, not every kind of it can be passed with Selenium.